# How do I create a connected graph given nodes and their positions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graph, graph-theory, procedural-generation

I'm trying to create a procedurally generated dungeon based game.
I have a set of rooms and I have the x,y coordinates of their midpoints.

What's the best way to create a connected graph based on these rooms' x,y coordinates?

[Rooms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLSEe.png)

I'm coding in C#, but feel free to post some pseudocode.

Edit: Edges may overlap. I previously said that I don't want edges to overlap but overlapping edges should be fine. I apologize for the confusion.

Thanks!

See the image: I want to connect the red rooms in a graph data structure.

Comment: The midpoints of the rooms aren't a good connection point. Where the doors will be is a better connection point.

Comment: Can you draw a sketch of what you have and what you want?

Comment: Hi - I updated the question and uploaded an image above. I previously said I don't want overlap, but this is fine. I just want to generate a random connected graph between these nodes in an efficient way.

Comment: @Morgoth - I'm not actually interested in creating the actual hallways at the moment. I'd just like to create a graph-like data structure so I can ensure my main rooms can reach each other. I should have clarified that, sorry!